# How to I get my burger menu JavaScript to work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following an online tutorial for a webpage, which is going grand except the responsive burger menu won't work - specifically the JS 'click' and 'show' function.

My navbar now also has a scroll function which appears when I shrink the page.

In fact, the JS isn't working for the entire site.
Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
document.querySelector('.menu-button').addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.querySelector('.main-menu').classList.toggle('show'));
```

```css
.main-nav .logo {
  width: 170px;
}

.nav-wrap {
  background-color: #000;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #fff;
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .main-nav ul.right-menu {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #7c7c7c;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: rgb(56, 56, 56) 1px solid;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="menu-button">
<i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
</div>
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Snowden Logo" class="logo">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="media.html">Media</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="right-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The error message in your snippet says it all really; there is no element with the class `menu-button`

Comment: where is `.menu-button` element in the html?

Comment: @Jamiec  that was a paste error on my behalf. Added it in there. Still not working

Comment: The menu opens. What should happen?

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt the burger menu won't open when I click it.

Comment: Ok, let's clarify: When I run your code above and click the three stacked bars a menu slides in from the left with the menu entries `Home`, `About`, `News`, etc. This does not work for you?

Comment: Ah I see. Yes, it works here - but not on my full website! Do you think there is code overwriting it? 

This is my first website project, so no idea where I might have gone wrong. I've been using various tutorials so finding it a bit difficult to make cohesive.

Answer (score 1):

Hei, I troubleshoot your code and I saw a very important thing that you did here. The media query. What you can see in your code is that it works under the condition that the page width is less than 700px. And this does not work always, for obvious reasons

I tried removing the media query option and leave all the code inside it to stand alone, that will work regardless of the page width.

So, your code from this

```
@media(max-width: 700px) {
  .menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .main-nav ul.right-menu {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #7c7c7c;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: rgb(56, 56, 56) 1px solid;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

will become this

```
.menu-button {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu-button:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .main-nav ul.right-menu {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #7c7c7c;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: rgb(56, 56, 56) 1px solid;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  .main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
```

Try to look at this demo I made [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2x3v01km/)

To simply tell you what you did wrong, the media query will allow your code to "work" only when the page is less than 700px wide. Without the media query, it will work always

**EDIT**

after the above solution, the author of the question had an issue that the burger menu was always visible and not working as intended. This is because the CSS is making the menu width 100% wide, thus making it around 1000px wide instead of 0 (hidden)

The solution to this is removing 2 lines of property in the CSS.

go here `.main-nav ul.main-menu` and remove those 2 lines of code `width: 50%; height: 100%;`. It is possible also to edit the width and change it from 50% to 20%. It will work too as intended

Comment: Thanks @noxter, however, this makes my navbar items disappear in full screen width! No JavaScript will work throughout my site, so I think there is an underlying problem.

Comment: I edited the above answer with a new solution to your issue, try it out and let me know